# Lembrar usuário e senha do Git ao fazer commits

Tags: git

Toda vez que faço um commit, o Git me solicita meu nome de usuário e minha senha. Existe alguma forma de gravar as credenciais em cache e evitar de ter que digitar toda hora?

Uso repositórios git com conexão HTTPS e não SSH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para guardar as credenciais, instale o `osxkeychain helper` fazendo:

```
git credential-osxkeychain
```

Em seguida, configure o `credential.helper` para armazenar suas credenciais.

No Mac:

```
git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
```

No Windows:

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

Answer (score 1):

Conforme descrito na sessão [7.4 Git Tools - Credential Storage](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage) do [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book):

> Se você usa o transporte *SSH* para se conectar à *Git* remotos, é
>   possível ter uma chave sem uma frase secreta, que permite transferir
>   dados com segurança sem digitar seu nome de usuário e senha. No
>   entanto, isso não é possível com os protocolos *HTTP* - cada conexão
>   precisa de um nome de usuário e senha. Isso fica ainda mais difícil
>   para sistemas com autenticação de dois fatores, onde o token usado por
>   uma senha é gerado aleatoriamente e impronunciável.
>
> Felizmente, **o Git possui um sistema de credenciais** que pode ajudar
>   nisso.
>
> Seguem algumas opções fornecidas pela ferramenta:
>
> - **O padrão é não armazenar em cache**. Cada conexão solicitará seu nome de usuário e senha.
> - O modo`cache`**mantém as credenciais na memória por um determinado período de tempo**. Nenhuma das senhas é armazenada no disco e elas são
>     removidas do cache após 15 minutos por padrão.
> - O modo`store`**salva as credenciais em um arquivo de texto** sem formatação no disco e elas **nunca expiram**. Isso significa
>     que, até você alterar sua senha para o host do *Git*, você nunca
>     precisará digitar suas credenciais novamente. A desvantagem dessa
>     abordagem é que suas **senhas são armazenadas em texto não criptografado**
>     em um arquivo simples em seu diretório inicial.
> - Se você estiver usando um *Mac*, o *Git* vem com um modo`osxkeychain`, que **armazena credenciais nas chaves seguras** anexadas à sua
>     conta do sistema. Esse método armazena as credenciais no disco e elas
>     nunca expiram, mas **elas são criptografadas com o mesmo sistema que
>     armazena certificados *HTTPS*** e preenchimentos automáticos do *Safari*.
> - Se você usa o *Windows*, pode instalar o [Gerenciador de Credenciais do Git para Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows). Isso é semelhante ao`osxkeychain`descrito acima, mas **usa o *Windows Credential Store* para
>     controlar informações confidenciais**.
>
> Você pode escolher um desses métodos definindo um valor de
>   configuração do Git:
>
> `$ git config --global credential.helper cache`
>
> Alguns desses comandos auxiliares possuem opções. O "store" aceita um
>   argumento `--file <caminho>`, que customiza onde o arquivo de texto
>   simples é salvo (o padrão é`~/.git-credentials`). O auxiliar “cache”
>   aceita a opção `--timeout <segundos>`, ​​que altera a quantidade de
>   tempo que seu daemon (que retém a senha) é mantido em execução (o
>   padrão é “900” ou 15 minutos).
>
> Veja um exemplo de como você configura
>   o auxiliar "store" com um nome de arquivo personalizado:
>
> `$ git config --global credential.helper 'store --file ~/.my-credentials'`