# Continua aparecendo Email e Senha mesmo depois de criado uma chave SSH

Tags: git, github, ssh

Criei uma chave `SSH` para usar no GitHub e mesmo seguindo todos os passos que foram o seguinte:

Utilizei o comando:

> `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`

Em seguida usei o comando `cat`:

> `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Depois de feito isso fui nas minhas configurações do GitHub e adicionei a chave, colei a `id_rsa.pub` e cliquei em adicionar.

[image: Chave SSH criada]

Quando eu vou fazer um novo `push` mesmo depois de tudo isso sendo feito, aparece:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Será que eu preciso reiniciar a máquina para que o mesmo funcione?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente você não está utilizando SSH, mas HTTPS para acesso ao repositório. <sup>[1](https://help.github.com/en/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use)</sup>

Para verificar seu repositório, execute na pasta do mesmo:

```
$ git remote -v
```

Se a URL de origem (*origin*) começa em `https://github.com/`, é porque utilizou a URL HTTPS.

Sendo assim, você deve considerar alterar a URL de origem para a URL SSH: <sup>[2](https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-a-remotes-url)</sup>

```
$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USUARIO/REPOSITORIO.git
```

Para supressão de senha sobre HTTPS, você deve utilizar o sistema de credenciais do Git, [conforme resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/366814/lembrar-usu%C3%A1rio-e-senha-do-git-ao-fazer-commits/366927#366927).

Comment: Obrigado! Foi esse mesmo o problema. Agora está tudo certo :)

Comment: Se a resposta foi satisfatória para o seu problema, por favor, marque-a como aceita, e nós dois ganhamos pontos, [veja](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta). Obrigado.

Comment: feito! Obrigado novamente :)